# How to implement "Who is talking?" feature in webrtc ios application?

Tags: ios, webrtc, libjingle, peer-connection

I am creating an ios application using webRTC for video conferencing. I want to detect who is talking in the peer connection.

To be more specific,I want to detect the audio activity of the remote peer I am connected to so that I can detect the person who is currently speaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be implemented by measuring the value of "audioOutputLevel"  in peer-connection stats reports. The Function that will you should study is

```
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection*)peerConnection didGetStats:(NSArray*)stats
```

Comment: I cannot find this method in pod 'WebRTC'. Can you please elaborate a little more? thanks.

Comment: The exact method can be found in https://cocoapods.org/pods/libjingle_peerconnection. But if you are using WebRTC pod try finding the similar delegate

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this guide](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios) for building a sample WebRTC iOS application.

Check the section **WebRTC Stats reporting**

> For example, audioSendInputLevel property indicates mic input level even while audio track disabled, so you can check if user is currently speaking/talking.

Comment: I don't want an api. i have implemented all features except this one.

Comment: Hey codeGeek, has there been some update on this issue so far? I would love to know how you solved your problem!

Comment: @DeveloBär This can be implemented by measuring the audio level in peerconnection stats. The Function that will you should study is - (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection*)peerConnection didGetStats:(NSArray*)stats